# Regex- First instance of Time in a string

Tags: regex, time

I am trying to build a regular expression that would pull the first time out of a string.

The issue is the time format is not standardized.

Here are the possible variations.

```
':' with 1 hour digit before the ':' (ex. 9:00 pm)
':' with 2 hour digits before the ':' (ex. 10:00pm)
no minutes with with 1 hour digit (ex 9pm)
no minutes with with 1 hour digit (ex 10pm)
```

Additionally there may or may not be a space before "am" or "pm"

Here is an example string.

```
7:30 pm -9 pm Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. 9pm-10pm Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
```

I would like this string to return `"7:30 pm"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify the tool you want to use, here a simple implementation using `sed`:

```
echo '7:30 pm -9 pm Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. 9pm-10pm Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text' | sed 's/\([0-2]\?[0-9]\(:[0-5][0-9]\)\? *[ap]m\).*/\1/i'
```

Legenda:

```
'[0-2]\?[0-9]'       match the hour (with 1 or 2 digits)
'\(:[0-5][0-9]\)\?'  match the minutes (optional)
' *'                 optional spaces
'[ap]m'              match am,pm,AM,PM (also Am,aM,pM,Pm)*
'.*'                 match all the rest of the string
```

In addiction: the external `\(...\)` create a group of all the above elements (a backreference) used later in the substitution part of the regex `\1`.
*: The last `/i` modifier make the regex case insensitive

You can rewrite all as a standard perl regex:

```
/(?i)[0-2]?\d(?::[0-5]\d)?\s*[ap]m/
```

Little ruby code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

input = "7:30 pm -9 pm Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. 9pm-10pm Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"
puts input[/(?i)[0-2]?\d(?::[0-5]\d)?\s*[ap]m/]
```

Comment: This solution seems to answer my question.  Am I missing any edge cases?

Comment: I've modified to relax space constraints (zero or more). What language do you want to use? We can split the regex into groups and format the output in some specific way. I've tried all the above cases before posting.

Comment: Now it is returning all of the times, not just the first.  I am using ruby.

Comment: @mferg I've added a ruby snippet, the ``variable[/regex/]`` form return only the first match (as needed).

Comment: Thanks Gsus.  This works great.  What are some good regex resources?

Comment: You can find some great info on this [site](http://www.regular-expressions.info) and for a really complete resource read "Mastering regular expressions" - O'reilly. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
(?i)\d{1,2}(?::\d{2})?\s*[ap]m
```

Explaining:

```
(?i)            # insensitive case
\d{1,2}         # one or two digits
(?:             # optional group
    :\d{2}      # the minutes
)?              # end optional group
\s*             # any spaces
[ap]m           # "am" or "pm"
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/rW1qO1/2)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.  This works great.  You are right I will need to set insensitive case for am AM Am pm PM Pm.  How do I adjust the regex for this?

Comment: This solution accept times with minutes over 59 and hours over 24. It is a little bit not real world applied

Answer (score 1):

A almost generic solution may be achieved using following expression:

```
([012]?\d(:[0-5]\d)?\s*(pm|am|PM|AM))
```

It considers capturing groups, getting all present time strings on string.

In javascript, it might be tested like following:

```
var testTime = "7:30 pm -9 pm Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. 9pm-10pm Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text";

var timeRex = /([012]?\d(:[0-5]\d)?\s*(pm|am|PM|AM))/g;

var firstTime = timeRex.exec(testTime)[0];

console.log(firstTime);
```

I really believe that there is a better general solution. I will try some more stable, then publish it here.

Comment: am|pm|AM|PM explicitaly for time focused solution, and not apply ignore-case for the whole analysis.

Comment: Good point.  The only other thing is that I only want to return the first time in the string.  How do you alter the regex for this case? Edit- Missed the 0 index to retrieve the first case.  How would you build this into the expression?

Comment: It should be used some non-greedy technique over this expression. Let's try something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
\d{1,2}\:?(?:\d{1,2}|)\s*[ap]m
```